# trying to pass my arrays (props) into my publish function as selector

Tags: arrays, reactjs, meteor, arguments, selector

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {check} from 'meteor/check';

export const Adressen = new Mongo.Collection('Phonebook');

if (Meteor.isServer) {

    Meteor.publish('ArrayToExport', function(branches) {
        check(branches, [Match.Any]);
        if(branches.length > 10){
            return this.ready()
        };
        return Adressen.find(
            {branche: {$in: branches}}, {fields: {firmenname:1, plz:1}}
        );
    });
}
```

.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import {Adressen} from "../api/MongoDB";

class ExportArray extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            branches: this.props.filteredBranches
        };
    }

    render(){

        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.exportArrays}></button>+
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default withTracker( (branches) => {

    Meteor.subscribe('ArrayToExport', branches);
    return {
        ArrayToExport: Adressen.find({}).fetch()
    };
})(ExportArray);
```

*this.props.filteredBranche* is a pure array,generated through controlled input field. *this.props.filteredBranches* changes as Input changes, in parent Component.
I thought I was sending my *this.props.filteredBranches* as an argument through *withTracker* function. But nothing is passed to the publish function.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    arrayExfct = function (array){
        return {
            find: {branche:{$in: array }},
            fields: {firmenname:1, plz:1}
        };
    }

    Meteor.publish('ArrayToExport', function (array) {
        return Adressen.find(
            arrayExfct(array).find, arrayExfct(array).fields);
    });
}
```

.

```
export default withTracker( () => {

    arrayExfct = function(array) {
        return {
            find: {branche: {$in:  array}},
            fields: {firmenname:1, plz:1}
        }
    }

    var array = ['10555'];
    Meteor.subscribe('ArrayToExport', array );
    var arrayExfct = Adressen.find(arrayExfct(array).find, arrayExfct(array).fields);
    return {
        ArrayToExport: Adressen.find({}).fetch()
    };
})(ExportArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you also added an example of where you used this component and how you pass props to it, but I think I see your problem.

You expect the local state in your rendering component to get into the withTracker container, but that would be the other way around. When you make the withTracker container, you are really making another react component that renders your display component (ExportArray) and passes the data (ArrayToExport) down into it.

So, props go like this currently:

external render -> withTracker component -> ExportArray

What you need to do it to get the filteredBranches (which you pass from a parent component?) from the props argument in withTracker and pass that to the subscribtion,

```
class ExportArray extends Component{

    exportArrays () {
        const { ArrayToExport } = this.props;
    }

    render(){
        const { ArrayToExport } = this.props;
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.exportArrays}></button>+
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default withTracker(propsFromParent => {
    const { filteredBranches } = propsFromParent;

    Meteor.subscribe('ArrayToExport', filteredBranches);

    return {
        ArrayToExport: Adressen.find({}).fetch()
    };
})(ExportArray);
```

Comment: I'll look into it! filteredBranches was indeed passed in from ParentComponent. <ExportArray filteredBranches={filteredBranches}/>

Answer (score 0):

Hi the issue is with the code below. The parameter called branches is the props so branches.branches is the array you passed in.

```
    export default withTracker( (branches) => {

    Meteor.subscribe('ArrayToExport', branches);
    return {
        ArrayToExport: Adressen.find({}).fetch()
    };
})(ExportArray);
```

Try the following.

```
    export default withTracker( ({branches}) => {

    Meteor.subscribe('ArrayToExport', branches);
    return {
        ArrayToExport: Adressen.find({}).fetch()
    };
})(ExportArray);
```

Notice all that changed was

```
(branches)
```

became

```
({branches})
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with a combination of Session Variables and State.

```
//Client
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import {Adressen} from "../api/MongoDB";
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Session } from 'meteor/session';

class ExportArray extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            x: [],
            y: []
        };
        this.exportArrays = this.exportArrays.bind(this);
    }

    exportArrays(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({x: this.props.filteredBranches});
        this.setState({y: this.props.filteredPostleitzahlen});
    }

    render(){
        var selector = {branche: {$in: this.state.x},plz: {$in: this.state.y}};

        Session.set('selector', selector);

        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.exportArrays}> Commit </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withTracker( () => {

    const ArrayfürExport = Meteor.subscribe('ArrayToExport', Session.get('selector') );
    return {
        ArrayToExport: Adressen.find({}).fetch()
    };
})(ExportArray);
```

//Server
    Meteor.publish('ArrayToExport', function (selector) {

```
        console.log('von mongodb', selector);

        return Adressen.find(
            selector
        , {
            fields: {firmenname:1, plz:1}
        });
    });
}
```